# What does Rory say to the Roman soldier in the Pandorica Opens episode of Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who

Does anyone know what Rory says to the Roman soldier in his first appearance in the [Pandorica Opens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pandorica_Opens) episode of Doctor Who?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Because Rory doesn't say anything to the soldier when he first appears (as Amy faints).

Comment: @Walt IMO he's the soldier outside River's tent volunteering. It's very unlikely it's been some ordinary legionary, so it had to be at least some centurio or someone with a message (which would again be unlikely given the situation and his reaction).

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought he meant the moment we actually *discover* it's Rory. Yeah, if that's the scene, it doesn't seem like we're supposed to understand what's muttered there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean the scene where Rory volunteers to accompany River back to the Pandorica. It's extremely hard to hear, but he says:

> Rory: I'll take my men. We can come unannounced. We'll help as much as...

The closed captioning matches this dialog, except it ends with "as much as possible". I watched several times and I don't believe the last word is audible, but I assume it was in the script the CC was dictated from.

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about the scene I think you do, then I don't think there's any specific or audible talk.

Considering the commander's lines right before and after Rory talking to him it's pretty obvious that he somehow volunteered to check the story of "fake Cleo":

> **Rory:** Sir?
>
> **Commander:** One moment.
>
> *(Both talking.)*
>
> **Commander:** Well, it seems you have a volunteer.

Considering Rory obviously didn't meet River earlier, I always assumed he arrived with the commander and therefore might have been some higher up (either indeed centurio or possible even more) and be trusted by the commander (given the fact he just okays him volunteering without asking further questions).

Later on Rory tells the Doctor about the other Romans at Stonehenge:

> **Rory:** Fifty men up top, volunteers. What about that thing?

So I assume he obviously offered to go there, together with his centuria. Considering a centuria typically had around 80 people (despite the name's origin) those might indeed all have been volunteers (so it's not just considered they volunteer just because their commanding officer says so).

Comment: They never did fully explain Rory's reincarnation as a member of the Auton Roman Legion.  I suppose we can speculate that when Amy re-imagined the Universe, she incorporated Rory, a bit of a paradox.

Comment: @Jeff-InventorChromeOS `They never did fully explain Rory's reincarnation as a member of the Auton Roman Legion` It's implied though, the Autons manufactured the Legion and Rory out of Amy's memories in order to trick her and The Doctor into trusting them so they could help lock him in the Pandorica which was a plan organised by all of the Doctor's enemies (including the Autons) who had teamed up.

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess it wouldn't have required future-Amy's intervention, then.